# How to use prototype inheritance without the "new" operator

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype

So im trying to make objects that have prototype inheritance without the "new" operator using closures. 
My code is:

```
var TABLE=function (tableId) {
var table=(document.getElementById(tableId)||{}),
    colName=[],
    rows,
    cols,
    selectedRow;

//private methods

    var updateRows=function(){
        //Code that updates the number of row of the table
    }
    updateRows();

//Declare the public methods for the object

var methods={
    prototype:{
        cols:function () {
        return cols;
        },
        rows:function () {
            return rows;
        }
    }
};
    return methods;
}

var table=Table("Inventory")
alert(table.rows()) //I get undefined
alert(table.prototype.rows()) //I get the actual number of rows
```

What am i doing wrong? Do you think i could use some better way of coding for this

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Prototype inheritance apparently works *with* new, so omitting it and then complaining won't really work. "I want to drive my car without tires". Too bad..

Comment: What are your reasons for wanting to use "prototype" in this situation? It seems to me your code would work as expected if you just remove the 'prototype' key in your methods structure? basically you don't seem to be needing any form of inheritance for what you are doing...

Comment: Have a look at the 'parasitic inheritance: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Comment: I just read the JavaScript: The Good Parts By Douglas Crockford. He actually recommends that we create objects avoiding the "new" operator. So i guest i would like to do that, and have prototypical inheritance. Im not an expert in javascript, but i would like to be one

Comment: What Douglas Crockford actually recommends is to use shallow inheritance where it is needed. From what I see of the above you do not require inheritance... but if you did it would be far better to use 'new' and use .prototype to a simple level. Just to add my own personal note I have been writing javascript apps, plugins and scripts for about 13 years now .. and I have never needed to use .prototype to achieve my goals - but without 'new' I wouldn't have got very far. The nearest I have come to "inheritance" has been to have one object instance used statically by lots of other instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use the new keyword in case you want to use prototypical inheritance.

The best to use with example :-

http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-inheritance-by-example/